# Transformations that preserve the metric

Tags: metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, vectors, notation, linear-algebra

I know that transformations that preserve the metric (like the Lorentz transformation, or rotations) have the property:

$$S^T \eta S = \eta$$

However, I'm getting: $S^TS = I$ and I'm not sure why:

$$\delta^i_j = \eta^{ik}\eta_{kj} = \eta^{ik}\langle \vec{e'_k}, \vec{e'_j}\rangle = \eta^{ik}\langle {S^m}_k\vec{e_m}, {S^n}_j\vec{e_n}\rangle = \eta^{ik}{S^m}_k{S^n}_j\langle \vec{e'_m}, \vec{e_n}\rangle = \eta^{ik}{S^m}_k{S^n}_j\eta_{mn} = \eta^{ik}S_{nk} {S^n}_j = {S_n}^i{S^n}_j = {(S^T)^i}_n{S^n}_j \implies S^TS =I$$

Where $\vec{e'_i}$ are the vectors in the new coordinates, and $\vec{e_i}$ are the vectors in the old coordinate system. I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: I'm not able to follow the calculation here, but I have left an answer below if that helps.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/456640/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by transformations that keep the metric tensor invariant, you mean that the components of $\eta$ do not change either. Under such a case, I think $S^TS = I$ should be OK.

Say we have a manifold with metric $g$. Now we pick a point $p$ on this manifold and, at this point, consider two frames, namely {${e_o, e_1, e_2,e_3}$} and {$\tilde{e}_o, \tilde{e}_1, \tilde{e}_2, \tilde{e}_3$}, then

the components $\eta_{ab}$ of the metric at $p$  can be calculated in one frame as
$$ \tilde{\eta}_{a b} =g\left(\widetilde{e}_a, \widetilde{e}_b\right) $$

Now, if we Lorentz transform to another frame, then

\begin{aligned}
\tilde{\eta}_{a b} &=g\left(\Lambda^m{ }_a e_m, \Lambda^n{ }_b e_n\right) \\
& =\Lambda^m{ }_a \Lambda^n{ }_b g\left(e_m, e_n\right) \\
& =\Lambda^m{ }_a \Lambda^n{ }_b \eta_{m n}
\end{aligned}

So if you say that $\tilde{\eta}_{ab} = \eta_{ab}$ then $\Lambda^m{ }_a \Lambda^n{ }_b = 1$.