# Lorentz Transformation of a Tensor

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus

If I have the electromagnetic field tensor, then, under a Lorentz transformation:

$$F^{'}_{\mu\nu} = \Lambda_{\mu}^{\alpha} \Lambda_{\nu}^{\beta} F_{\alpha\beta} $$

I know that the Lorentz matrix is orthogonal, then:

$$\Lambda_{\mu}^{\alpha} \Lambda_{\mu}^{\beta}  = \delta_{\alpha}^{\beta}$$

So, for every diagonal element with $ \mu = \nu $,

$$F^{'}_{\mu\mu} = \delta_{\alpha}^{\beta} \ F_{\alpha\beta} = F_{\alpha\alpha}$$

Is this correct? For every tensor, the diagonal elements will not change under a Lorentz transformation?

Comment: [The Lorentz Transformation matrix is only orthogonal with respect to the metric](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/349030/157014), so I think your 'orthogonality' equation is not strictly correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your second equation is not a proper tensor equation, as the RHS has $\alpha$ downstairs, where in the LHS it is upstairs.
In order to have a correct relationship, you need to sum over an upstairs and a downstairs $\mu$, otherwise you will be left with a $\mu$ in the RHS.

Comment: This might be a useful explanation: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/349030/268151